# String Split with comma and newline

Tags: r, tidyr, stringr

I have a string which looks like

```
'"aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd","eee"\n"1","2","3","4","5"\n"6","7","8","9","10"'
```

I want to split by comma and newline and convert it into a dataframe and get the output as

```
aaa bbb ccc ddd eee
1   2   3   4  5
6   7   8   9  10
```

Is there any way to do it in R?

Comment: What is `s`? It is not a valid R object.

Comment: @suren I just edited it. I just have a string and needs to be converted to a dataframe of the above format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your string is

```
s = '"aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd","eee"\n"1","2","3","4","5"\n"6","7","8","9","10"'
```

then perhaps you can try

```
> read.table(text = s, header = TRUE, sep = ",")
  aaa bbb ccc ddd eee
1   1   2   3   4   5
2   6   7   8   9  10
```

---

A shorter one (thank to comments from @akrun) is with `data.table::fread`

```
> fread(s)
   aaa bbb ccc ddd eee
1:   1   2   3   4   5
2:   6   7   8   9  10
```

or `read.csv` (thank to comments from @thelatemail)

```
> read.csv(text = s)
  aaa bbb ccc ddd eee
1   1   2   3   4   5
2   6   7   8   9  10
```

Comment: This is a csv, so use `read.csv` - `read.csv(text=x)`

Comment: @thelatemail Thanks you as well

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option using `read.table`, although for this to work I removed some quotes, commas, and newlines (replaced with actual new lines).

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, 
                 text="aaa bbb ccc ddd eee 
                 1 2 3 4 5 
                 6 7 8 9 10")
```

Output:

```
  aaa bbb ccc ddd eee
1   1   2   3   4   5
2   6   7   8   9  10
```

Comment: Thank you but is it possible without replacing with actual newlines?